# how to install Windows 10 universal development tools in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have visual studio community 2015 and I cant build windows 10 universal apps because of universal development tools installation.

After a search I found that it can be downloaded from [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads) under 'Other download options' and after installation when I'm try to begin new project it says 'install universal development tools'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally the problem is finished !!
just after my previews downloads I downloaded [Windows 10 Developer Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/1/4011ECDA-7484-4CEA-A53E-6C73A32A6793/Windows_VSTools.exe).

now you will be able to build UWP.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a time ago. Got to Programs and Features and search for VS 2015. Then hit the "Uninstall, Change" Button. In the Visual Studio Manager, click at "Change" and check all options for Windows 10 developing.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks but I've tried this before and it stuck at 'Tools for Windows 10 Universal Apps (Windows SDK 10.0.10240)'